# Time difference based on Sundays in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    the_debt_id varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_paid timestamp NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_due date NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('LMUS01', '2019-05-03 09:00:01', '2019-05-02'), 
       ('LMUS01', '2019-06-03 10:45:12', '2019-06-02'), 
       ('LMUS01', '2019-07-01 15:39:58', '2019-07-02'), 
       ('LMUS02', '2019-05-03 19:43:44', '2019-05-07'), 
       ('LMUS02', '2019-06-07 08:37:05', '2019-06-07')
```

I want the date difference but some of the payment days `the_debt_due` fall on Sunday (like June 07). If the payment day fall on Sunday, I want to add 1 to the `the_debt_due`, so the difference for good payers is 0 or negative (paid in advance).

The result should follow:

```
SELECT (date(the_debt_paid) - the_debt_due) AS date_diff 
FROM my_table
```

But I don't know how to tell what day is Sunday to the previous query.

Expected output

```
date_diff
1
0
-1
-4
0
```

Note that the second row is 0 because the due date fell on Sunday.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As I explained before: `extract(day from ..)` does **not** give you the length of the interval in days.

Comment: Hello @a_horse_with_no_name, I edited my question to the right difference of days. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(extract dow from ...)` to get the day of the week of a given date, where Sunday is day of week 0.

This would do what you want:

```
select 
    t.*, 
    date(the_debt_paid) 
        - the_debt_due 
        - (extract(dow from the_debt_due) = 0)::int AS date_diff 
from my_table t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ac2fbd3b81788d9d747a451499f2cc90)**:

```
the_debt_id | the_debt_paid       | the_debt_due | date_diff
:---------- | :------------------ | :----------- | --------:
LMUS01      | 2019-05-03 09:00:01 | 2019-05-02   |         1
LMUS01      | 2019-06-03 10:45:12 | 2019-06-02   |         0
LMUS01      | 2019-07-01 15:39:58 | 2019-07-02   |        -1
LMUS02      | 2019-05-03 19:43:44 | 2019-05-07   |        -4
LMUS02      | 2019-06-07 08:37:05 | 2019-06-07   |         0
```

Comment: Hello @GMB, you know that's a great answer!, just a question please, when you apply `(extract(dow from the_debt_due) = 0)` is it evaluating as a logic expression? I mean, if the expression is true, returns 1?

Comment: @Manu: yes. The conditin returns a boolean, that we then cast to an `int`; `true` becomes `1`, and `false` becomes `0 .

Comment: Thank you very much @GMB! I have tested for Saturday and Sunday and worked in a fantastic way!, it made me investigate more, I appreciate your time and answer. Have a great day!